# Wordpress Duplicator plugin failed "Required Path" using XAMPP

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

Im having troubles with Duplicator pluging in my local. Im preparing it for migration but now stuck with this path error. What did i do wrong in my installation?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the permission of htdocs folder and subdirectories to 755 and try it again.